# What is the correct way to take the most recent data in a reactivex ReplaySubject?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, system.reactive, reactivex

I'm new to reactivex (.NET) and I need help with the following problem.

I have a `ReplaySubject` constructed by passing a time interval of 1 hour.
It continuously receives data from a sensor.
I want to have "something" that only gives access to the most recent data that has already arrived within a certain amount of time (e.g. one minute).
This amount of time is not pre-defined. It is not known at the time the `ReplaySubject` is constructed. Receiving the most recent data in a `List<T>` is sufficient.

Which and how reactivex operators can be used? Can you propose a solution?

I've already tried several operators, in particular the ones with "last" in the name but with no success because they wait for the `ReplaySubject` to complete.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] resembling your current (not working to your liking) solution?

Comment: Is it an option to use two `ReplySubject<T>`s, one with one hour window, and another with one minute window, and populate both with the same data?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, Unfortunately no, it is not an option because the period is not pre-defined.

Comment: Does the Data have a timestamp, so you can Linq-Filter for it ?

Comment: Do you want just a list with the most recent data, or instead an observable sequence with the most recent data **and** the future data?

Comment: @Fildor, no, the data doesn't have a timestamp, maybe ReplaySubject adds it behind the scenes but I don't know how to get it

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, a list is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to do this:

```
ReplaySubject<int> rs = new(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0));
```

The subject will only replay values from within the `TimeSpan` parameter.

---

If the timespan is changing perhaps play with something like this:

```
Subject<TimeSpan> t = new();
Subject<int> s = new();

IObservable<int> cq = t.Select(t => s.Replay(t).RefCount()).Switch();
```

Comment: The OP has [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75542619/what-is-the-correct-way-to-take-the-most-recent-data-in-a-reactivex-replaysubjec/75588323#comment133281806_75542619) that *"the period is not pre-defined"*. The *"one minute"* is just an example.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Well, in the comments. One does not have time to read all of the comments. The OP should update the question when salient information presents itself.

Comment: You are right. I edited the question and added the information posted by the OP in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The `ReplaySubject<T>` stores internally timestamp information for each buffered element ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/85f1eb7c53e27cccdbeee3e0b044916168843fcc/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Subjects/ReplaySubject.cs#L478)), but it doesn't expose this information. So, unless you are willing to implement a custom `ReplaySubject<T>` from scratch, you'll have to duplicate this information. You could use the [`DateTime.UtcNow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.utcnow), or a [`Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch) as the native implementation, or the [`Environment.TickCount64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.tickcount64) property as in the example below:

```
ReplaySubject<(Item Value, long TimeStamp)> subject = new(
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60.0), Scheduler.Immediate);

//...

subject.OnNext((new Item(), Environment.TickCount64));

//...

long now = Environment.TickCount64; // Milliseconds elapsed since the system started
Item[] recent = subject
    .Where(e => e.TimeStamp >= now - 60_000) // Last 60 seconds
    .Select(e => e.Value)
    .TakeImmediate()
    .ToArray()
    .Wait();
```

The `TakeImmediate` operator propagates the elements that are pushed synchronously during the subscription, and then immediately completes:

```
private static IObservable<T> TakeImmediate<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
    {
        source.Subscribe(observer).Dispose();
        observer.OnCompleted();
        return Disposable.Empty;
    });
}
```

Configuring the `ReplaySubject<T>` with the `Scheduler.Immediate` is required in order for the `TakeImmediate` operator to work correctly (to not filter-out very recent items).